# mysql SELECT with 'A' from php array does not work (because `A` in php and mysql looks the same, but one written in Russian, another in English)

Tags: php, mysql

Array `$_POST` contains

```
(
[first_subcat] => А
[process_first_subcat_name_for_url] => 1
)
```

I know that in mysql for column `FirstSubtopicName` one field value is A (varchar field).

Query is

```
SELECT TopicName FROM topics WHERE FirstSubtopicName = ?
$stmt->execute( array( $_POST['first_subcat'] ) );
```

And get empty array

But such query works

```
SELECT TopicName FROM topics WHERE FirstSubtopicName = ?
$stmt->execute( array( 'A' ) );
```

Also works

```
SELECT TopicName FROM topics WHERE FirstSubtopicName = 'A'
```

Also works if define `$_POST['first_subcat'] = 'A';`

Tried to change to `$stmt->execute( array( '\''.$_POST['first_subcat']. '\'' ) );` Get empty.

Tried to change to `'?'`. Also empty

What I am doing wrong?

Found that it is because that `А` is written in non latin (`А` is written in Russian).

Changed to `А` to `А буква` (to check) and now seems all works. Seems in mysql I had `A` as latin character, but in POST was A in russian...

Comment: Then the incoming post variable doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: Try to `print_r()` the `$_POST` contents.

Comment: Check your var with `var_dump($_POST['first_subcat']);` This way u can detect extra whitespaces and stuff

Comment: If you found the cause, please delete the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I modified question tittle. Question may be useful for other people. I spend about half an hour or more when found reason. If I saw such information as wrote here, I would check languages instead of checking other reasons.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ITYM If you found the cause, please write an appropriate answer so that others can benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation reason was the following

`A` - letter written in English

`А` - letter written in Russian (кириллица, like `С Д Ф Г Х` etc.)

In mysql `A` was in English. But in `SELECT` query `А` was in Russian.

Both `A` looks the same, but for `SELECT` query they are different. That is because I got empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the query is looking for a string.
Check with

`$stmt->execute( array( (string)$_POST['first_subcat'] ) );`